# Why is my boolean value not changing in Java?

Tags: java, loops, boolean

Sorry first of all if this is basic and I'm missing something obvious, but my professor has given me a bit of an overwhelming project and I need a bit of help. We're supposed to make the board game Trouble (without a GUI). I have a boolean value "playing" that is set to false for the players who are not taking a turn and "true" for the players who are taking a turn. I have methods specific to the player color to check weather the board is clear so that the player can move his/her piece out of the home section when they roll a six, but when I try to run my loop that cycles through the array of players, it tells me that "playing" is set to "true" for all of them. I even manually set "playing" to false right at the beginning of my loop, but that didn't even change it, so maybe something is wrong with my set method? Here is some of my code:

```
    public void setPlaying(boolean set)
   {  
      if (set == false)
         playing = false;
      else
         playing = true;
   }



   for (int index = 0; index < totPlayers; index++)
            {
               players[index].setPlaying(false);
               if (players[index].getColor().equals("red") && players[index].getPlaying())
               {
                  Board.checkClearRed();
                  System.out.println("Player " + index + " is playing");
                  System.out.println(players[index].getOrder());
               }
               else if (players[index].getColor().equals("blue") && players[index].getPlaying())
               {
                  Board.checkClearBlue();
                  System.out.println("Player " + index + " is playing");
                  System.out.println(players[index].getOrder());
               }
               else if (players[index].getColor().equals("green") && players[index].getPlaying())
               {
                  Board.checkClearGreen();
                  System.out.println("Player " + index + " is playing");
                  System.out.println(players[index].getOrder());
               }
               else
               {
                  Board.checkClearYellow();
                  System.out.println("Player " + index + " is playing");
                  System.out.println(players[index].getOrder());
               }
            }
```

Pasting seems to have messed up the spacing of my brackets a little bit, but it is still very readable I think. The print methods are in there just for my testing purposes.

Comment: You mean `.getPlaying()` always returns true? Can you show that method?

Comment: Fwiw, your professor may frown at you not explicitly using curlies in your if/else in your setter...its a bug waiting to hatch. I don't see how playing is set to true in the code posted...I would do a CTRL-f in netbeans and search for "playing=" or "this.playing=" or any other search term that would narrow down results to anywhere "playing" gets assigned something. It's actually a really handy way to speed up debugging. If that's not it, then donfuxx may be right it could be a brainfart getter

Comment: My advice - write a test first then write code until the test passes.  Or since you already written code write a junit test to find your error. -- and yes, brace all of your conditionals

Comment: @donfuxx Thanks everyone for the speedy replies. Yeah I meant to show the .getPlaying() method... my bad. I actually fixed it though by just splitting it up and putting an if (getPlaying()) statement first, then looping it. For some reason that did the trick. I'll fix the curly braces too! I guess I've gotten into a bad habit of not using them when I don't need them.

Comment: @justin Thanks for the reply, I got it working...see above.

Comment: @mortsahl Thanks for the reply, I got it working...see above.